# HTML colspan and rowspan not working

Tags: html, css

I have got a table 18 columns by 7 rows and i want to make `td` element to take 10 columns and 3 rows,so here is my code

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="groups group1">1</td>
      <td class="groups group2">2</td>
      <td class="groups group3">3</td>
      <td class="groups group4">4</td>
      <td class="groups group5">5</td>
      <td class="groups group6">6</td>
      <td class="groups group7">7</td>
      <td class="groups group8">8</td>
      <td class="groups group9">9</td>
      <td class="groups group10">10</td>
      <td class="groups group11">11</td>
      <td class="groups group12">12</td>
      <td class="groups group13">13</td>
      <td class="groups group14">14</td>
      <td class="groups group15">15</td>
      <td class="groups group16">16</td>
      <td class="groups group17">17</td>
      <td class="groups group18">18</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="periods period1">
      <th>1</th>
      <td class="element" id="H"></td>
      <td class="basic_info">
        <span class="info_big"><span class="info_spans">Protons</span></span>
      </td>
      <td class="biginfo" colspan="10" rowspan="3"></td>
      <td class="element" id="He"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="periods period2">
      <th>2</th>
      <td class="element" id="Li"></td>
      <td class="element" id="Be"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="periods period3">
      <th>3</th>
      <td class="element" id="Na"></td>
      <td class="element" id="Mg"></td>
      <td class="element" id="Al"></td>
      <td class="element" id="Si"></td>
      <tr class="periods period4">
        <th>4</th>
        <td class="element" id="K"></td>
        <td class="element" id="Ca"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="periods period5">
        <th>5</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="periods period6">
        <th>6</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="periods period7">
        <th>7</th>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As you see `bigInfo` has an attribute of `colspan` equal to 10 and `rowspan` equal to 3,but unfortunately i only get cell 6 by 70 with a padding of 1 while i want that row to take a width of 10 columns and 3 rows.

Comment: check your code, there is a missing `</span>`

Comment: @TemaniAfif i'm sure thats not the problem,but thanks for pointing that out

Comment: can you also post all the relevent code, with CSS too ? so we can easily see the issue

Comment: You write in your question, that your table has 18 columns, but in your code the row with the most columns has 15 (row 3, when counting the 10 columns from biginfo). So, either you had a typo or there is a big part of the code missing.

Comment: @Geshode i added thead also

Comment: @askoasksao please insert your output screenshot so that its clear what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A table that large with a odd block of spans is difficult to visualize in HTML. Mark the `<td>` by column.row and determine the col.row coords are for each of the span's corners.

**Details commented in Demo**

### Demo

```css
table, td {outline:1px solid blue}
td {padding:2px;}
```

```html
<!--7x18 | 3x10
Get the 4 corners as row.column coordinates
start at the top left corner then continue in a 
clockwise direction.
1. To determine the left corner columns, count the
   number of columns before the big span begins:
   
Start=3

2. Next add start number to the min and max of colspan:

Start=3 Min=1 
Left Corners=4

Start=3 Max=10
Right Corners=13

3. The row numbers are done the same way but vertically.

Top Left (Start). 1.4
Top Right........ 1.13
Bottom Right..... 3.13
Bottom Left (End) 3.4
-->
<table>
<tr>
<td>1.1</td><td>1.2</td><td>1.3</td>
<td colspan='10' rowspan='3'>1.4---------------------------------------1.13<br>
3.4---------------------------------------3.13</td>
<td>1.14</td><td>1.15</td><td>1.16</td><td>1.17</td><td>1.18</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2.1</td><td>2.2</td><td>2.3</td>
<td>2.x</td><td>2.x</td><td>2.x</td><td>2.x</td><td>2.x</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3.1</td><td>3.2</td><td>3.3</td>
<td>3.x</td><td>3.x</td><td>3.x</td><td>3.x</td><td>3.x</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4.1</td><td>4.2</td><td>4.3</td><td>4.x</td><td>4.x</td><td>4.x</td><td>4.x</td><td>4.x</td><td>4.x</td><td>4.x</td><td>4.x</td><td>4.x</td><td>4.x</td><td>4.x</td><td>4.x</td><td>4.x</td><td>4.x</td><td>4.x</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5.1</td><td>5.2</td><td>5.3</td><td>5.x</td><td>5.x</td><td>5.x</td><td>5.x</td><td>5.x</td><td>5.x</td><td>5.x</td><td>5.x</td><td>5.x</td><td>5.x</td><td>5.x</td><td>5.x</td><td>5.x</td><td>5.x</td><td>5.x</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>6.1</td><td>6.2</td><td>6.3</td><td>6.x</td><td>6.x</td><td>6.x</td><td>6.x</td><td>6.x</td><td>6.x</td><td>6.x</td><td>6.x</td><td>6.x</td><td>6.x</td><td>6.x</td><td>6.x</td><td>6.x</td><td>6.x</td><td>6.x</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>7.1</td><td>7.2</td><td>7.3</td><td>7.x</td><td>7.x</td><td>7.x</td><td>7.x</td><td>7.x</td><td>7.x</td><td>7.x</td><td>7.x</td><td>7.x</td><td>7.x</td><td>7.x</td><td>7.x</td><td>7.x</td><td>7.x</td><td>7.x</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code wasn't valid, you had some missing tags. Additional there is no `<table>` tag at all, don't know how your fully code is looking, but i updated it and it seems to work how it should!

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="groups group1">1</td>
      <td class="groups group2">2</td>
      <td class="groups group3">3</td>
      <td class="groups group4">4</td>
      <td class="groups group5">5</td>
      <td class="groups group6">6</td>
      <td class="groups group7">7</td>
      <td class="groups group8">8</td>
      <td class="groups group9">9</td>
      <td class="groups group10">10</td>
      <td class="groups group11">11</td>
      <td class="groups group12">12</td>
      <td class="groups group13">13</td>
      <td class="groups group14">14</td>
      <td class="groups group15">15</td>
      <td class="groups group16">16</td>
      <td class="groups group17">17</td>
      <td class="groups group18">18</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="periods period1">
        <th>1</th>
        <td class="element" id="H"></td>
        <td class="basic_info">
            <span class="info_big"></span>
            <span class="info_spans">Protons</span>
        </td>
        <td class="biginfo" colspan="10" rowspan="3"></td>
        <td class="element" id="He"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="periods period2">
        <th>2</th>
        <td class="element" id="Li"></td>
        <td class="element" id="Be"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="periods period3">
        <th>3</th>
        <td class="element" id="Na"></td>
        <td class="element" id="Mg"></td>
        <td class="element" id="Al"></td>
        <td class="element" id="Si"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="periods period4">
        <th>4</th>
    <td class="element" id="K"></td>
        <td class="element" id="Ca"></td></tr>
    <tr class="periods period5">
        <th>5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="periods period6">
        <th>6</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="periods period7">
        <th>7</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```